# Show that the vector space of continuous functions on $X$ is linearly isomorphic to the vector space of all convergent sequences in $\Bbb R$.

Tags: metric-spaces

Consider the set $X = \{\frac 1n : n \in \Bbb N \} \cup\{\ 0\}$ with the induced metric of $\Bbb R$. Show that the vector space of continuous functions on $X$ is linearly isomorphic to the vector space of all convergent sequences in $\Bbb R$.

Facing difficulty to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to show that a real sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent to a limit $L$ if and only if the function $f \colon X\to\mathbb R$ given by $f(1/n)=x_n$ and $f(0)=L$ is continuous.

This should give you one-to-one correspondence between convergent sequence and continuous functions on the space $X$ defined in your question. Once you have this bijection, it should be relatively easy to show that it is a isomorphism of vector spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $\mathcal C(X,\mathbb R)$ the vector space of continuous functions on $X$. Since $X\setminus \{0\}$ is a discrete subset of $\mathbb R$, we see that every map $f\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is automatically continuous on $X\setminus\{0\}$. This shows that $\mathcal C(X,\mathbb R)$ is actually the set of all maps $X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ that are continuous at $0$, i.e. $\mathcal C(X,\mathbb R) = \{f\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb R\mid f(\tfrac 1n) \rightarrow f(0) \text{ for $n\to\infty$}\}$.

Now let $Y = \{(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\mid (a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N} \text{ converges}\}$ and consider the linear map $\varphi\colon\mathcal C(X,\mathbb R) \rightarrow Y$, $f\mapsto (f(\tfrac 1n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$. This map is well-defined because of $f(\tfrac 1n)\rightarrow f(0)$ for $n\to\infty$.

For injectivity let $f\in \mathcal C(X,\mathbb R)$ such that $\varphi(f) = (0)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. But this means $f(\tfrac 1n) = 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and, by continuity of $f$, $f(0) =0$, i.e. $f=0$ in $\mathcal C(X,\mathbb R)$. This shows that $\varphi$ is injective.

For surjectivity let $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}\in Y$. Define $f\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ by $f(\tfrac 1n) := a_n$ and $f(0) := \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$. $f$ is continuous because of $f(0) = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(\tfrac 1n)$ so that $f\in \mathcal C(X,\mathbb R)$ (remember that checking continuity at $0$ is sufficient). Obviously we have $\varphi(f) = (a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and this shows surjectivity.

All in all we have shown that $\mathcal C(X,\mathbb R)$ and $Y$ are isomorphic as vector spaces.